# Check query of points inside Simple Polygon

Tags: geometry

I am having a problem about checking that a point lies inside a Simple Polygon or not. But, the number of verticals of Polygon is N <= 100000 and the Query has M <= 100000 points. I got TLE with O(M * N). Can someone give me an solution with this problem ?
This is the problem: https://oj.vnoi.info/problem/icpc21_beta_a

Comment: Build [Trapezoidal Decomposition](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/m.slater/Teaching/CG/1997-98/Solutions/Trap/) of polygon and perform logarithmic searching over trapezoids

Comment: Sort both the polygon elements as well as the points by their x-axis and run a sweep algorithm across that data. This approach should be fast (as it does the polygon analysis and the solution finding in one go) and require very little memory (as most sweep algorithms do).